# Regex - Exclude brackets and brackets with special key

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I got this string:

```
[[Fil:Hoganas_hamn.jpg|miniatyr|Höganäs Hamn.]] [[Fil:Hoganas_hamn_kvickbadet.jpg|miniatyr|Höganäs Hamn - Kvickbadet.]] [[Fil:Höganäs Jefast ny redigerad-1.jpg|miniatyr|Jefasthuset sett från väster med en del av den nya bryggan vid Kvickbadet.]] '''Höganäs''' är en [[tätort]] och [[centralort]] i [[Höganäs kommun]] i [[Skåne län]]. Höganäs blev stad 1936. Ursprungligen är Höganäs ett [[fiskeläge]] kring vilket en [[gruvindustri]] utvecklades för brytning av [[kol (bränsle)|kol]] och [[lera|leror]] för tillverkning av [[eldfast]] [[keramik]] ([[Höganäskrus]]). Gruvindustrin är numera nedlagd.
```

I want to exclude every instance of [[FIL: + dynamic word]] and every [[, ]], but not exclude the word itself when its only [[word]] without the "FIL:" in it.

I've begun doing a regex for it but I'm stuck.

```
\[\[\Fil:|\]\]
```

The output Im after should look like this:

```
'''Höganäs''' är en tätort och centralort i Höganäs kommun i Skåne län. Höganäs blev stad 1936. Ursprungligen är Höganäs ett fiskeläge kring vilket en gruvindustri utvecklades för brytning av kol (bränsle)|kol och lera|leror för tillverkning av eldfast keramik (Höganäskrus). Gruvindustrin är numera nedlagd.
```

I have JQuery but think .replace should do the trick?

Comment: this looks like it's from some markup language. did you make this language up, or is it an existing one? maybe you can get a parser for it.

Comment: @Mark It's from wikipedia, yeah maybe I could get a parser for it instead, but I don't want it to be links, just plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing all matches for this Regex with an empty string:

```
\[\[Fil:[^\]]*\]\]|\[\[|\]\]
```

To break this down:

```
\[\[Fil:[^\]]*\]\]   matches [[Fil:...]]
\[\[                  matches remaining [[
\]\]                  matches remaining ]]
|                     combines with OR
```

To get your exact output, you may need to strip some whitespace as well:

```
\[\[Fil:[^\]]*\]\]\s+|\[\[|\]\]
```

So, in JavaScript, you could write:

```
x.replace(/\[\[Fil:[^\]]*\]\]\s+|\[\[|\]\]/g, '');
```

Comment: Yeah, this works on Reggy but when I try to implement it in javascript it doesn't?

x.replace(/\[\[\Fil:[^\]]*\]\]|\[\[|\]\]/, '')

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hard to tell in your comment, as there are a lot of backwards slashes missing there... Have tested in JavaScript as well and works here.

Comment: Add a trailing g flag to the regex: 
`x = x.replace(/\[\[\Fil:[^\]]*\]\]|\[\[|\]\]/g, '')`. This makes it a global search - without, it only matches the first [[Fil:...]] entry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, maybe you want also to adjust spaces

```
var string = "[[Fil:Hoganas_hamn.jpg|miniatyr|Höganäs Hamn.]] [[Fil:Hoganas_hamn_kvickbadet.jpg|miniatyr|Höganäs Hamn - Kvickbadet.]] [[Fil:Höganäs Jefast ny redigerad-1.jpg|miniatyr|Jefasthuset sett från väster med en del av den nya bryggan vid Kvickbadet.]] '''Höganäs''' är en [[tätort]] och [[centralort]] i [[Höganäs kommun]] i [[Skåne län]]. Höganäs blev stad 1936. Ursprungligen är Höganäs ett [[fiskeläge]] kring vilket en [[gruvindustri]] utvecklades för brytning av [[kol (bränsle)|kol]] och [[lera|leror]] för tillverkning av [[eldfast]] [[keramik]] ([[Höganäskrus]]). Gruvindustrin är numera nedlagd.";

var result = string.replace(/\[\[Fil:.*?\]\]/g, '').replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah, this one worked too, but I will stick with Davids solution, one replace. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this

```
\[\[.*?\]\]
```

And then use the callback function version of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to check if starts with `Fil:` then conditionally decide whether you want to return a blank string to erase it, or just the word itself.

Alternately, use 2 regexes. Replace the `Fil:` ones with a blank string first, and then the rest with just the word. You can use

```
\[\[(\w+)\]\]
```

Or something similar to catch the `[[word]]` ones and then replace it with a backreference to the word, i.e., `\1` refers to what's in parentheses.